# Python 2.7.6 - For loop is not working with the nmap module

Tags: python, python-2.7, nmap, inetaddress

I have been at this for hours and I cannot figure it out. The script is supposed to scan servers for port 22. However, the very last line of the code errors out with "KeyError". What is confusing is that this only happens when I use a FOR loop or I create a function and pass it the value.

If the code is out of a loop the last line works, no matter if it is a hard coded IP or a variable.

If at the last line I enter loop_1 with out the single quotes I get the following error: 
**Wrong type for [host], should be a string was class 'netaddr.ip.IPAddress'**

I converted it to a string by adding just before the last line of the code.

```
value = str(loop_1)
```

That in turns gives an error of:
KeyError: '10.0.0.0'

Here is the script.

```
import nmap
from netaddr import *

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

for loop_1 in IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/26'):
    print nm.scan('loop_1', '22')
    print nm['loop_1']['tcp'][22]['state']
```

Answer (score 3):

If the address is not up and reachable you will get a keyerror from nmap:

```
import nmap
from netaddr import IPNetwork

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

for loop_1 in IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/26'):
    print(nm.scan(loop_1.format(), '22'))
    try:
       print(nm[loop_1.format()]['tcp'][22]['state'])
    except KeyError as e:
        pass
```

working in ipython:

```
In [5]: paste
import nmap
from netaddr import IPNetwork

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

for loop_1 in IPNetwork('192.168.43.65/30'):
    print(loop_1)
    print(nm.scan(loop_1.format(), '22'))
    try:
       print(nm[loop_1.format()]['tcp'][22]['state'])
    except KeyError as e:
        pass

    ## -- End pasted text --
    192.168.43.64
    {'nmap': {'scanstats': {'uphosts': u'0', 'timestr': u'Wed Dec 24 02:41:51 2014', 'downhosts': u'1', 'totalhosts': u'1', 'elapsed': u'3.06'}, 'scaninfo': {u'tcp': {'services': u'22', 'method': u'connect'}}, 'command_line': u'nmap -oX - -p 22 -sV 192.168.43.64'}, 'scan': {}}
    192.168.43.65
    {'nmap': {'scanstats': {'uphosts': u'0', 'timestr': u'Wed Dec 24 02:41:55 2014', 'downhosts': u'1', 'totalhosts': u'1', 'elapsed': u'3.05'}, 'scaninfo': {u'tcp': {'services': u'22', 'method': u'connect'}}, 'command_line': u'nmap -oX - -p 22 -sV 192.168.43.65'}, 'scan': {}}
    192.168.43.66
    {'nmap': {'scanstats': {'uphosts': u'1', 'timestr': u'Wed Dec 24 02:42:01 2014', 'downhosts': u'0', 'totalhosts': u'1', 'elapsed': u'6.14'}, 'scaninfo': {u'tcp': {'services': u'22', 'method': u'connect'}}, 'command_line': u'nmap -oX - -p 22 -sV 192.168.43.66'}, 'scan': {u'192.168.43.66': {'status': {'state': u'up', 'reason': u'syn-ack'}, 'hostname': u'lab', 'vendor': {}, 'addresses': {u'ipv4': u'192.168.43.66'}, u'tcp': {22: {'product': '', 'state': u'open', 'version': '', 'name': u'ssh', 'conf': u'10', 'extrainfo': u'protocol 2.0', 'reason': u'syn-ack', 'cpe': ''}}}}}
    open # only address up so only open or closed received
```

If you want  a list of ips and whether the port is open or not up can use nmap exclusively:

```
nm = nmap.PortScanner()

nm.scan(hosts='10.0.0.0/26',ports="22")
results = [[ip, nm[ip]['tcp'][22]['state']] for ip in nm.all_hosts()]

print("ip {}".format(" ".join(*results)))
ip 10.0.0.1 open
....
```

Comment: Right. I can reach up to that point but it still does not solve the issue with line

     print nm['loop_1']['tcp'][22]['state']

This line, if not part of a loop or a function will print the state of port 22.

Comment: I was using 'loop_1' but it just prints the key "scan". The same goes if I use print print(nm[loop_1.format()]['tcp'][22]['state'])

Comment: it prints open or closed for me `open`, don't use nm['loop_1'] that is simply using the string `'loop_1'`, are you using the code exactly as posted?

Comment: Right. What I am trying to do, which I am not able to do in my original code, is to just have it return "Open" or "Close" while ignoring all the other info. That is the main problem that I have. I do not know how to isolate it. I just want that particular information nothing else.

Comment: I will add the code running and working on my machine, it works exactly as you want but you will only see open or closed when you have an ip that is **up** emphasis on the up

Comment: to see an example, pass your local ip as a string like `"192.168.43.65"` in place of `loop_1.format()` an you will see what I mean

Comment: I am playing around with and I am starting to understand what you originally said. My original code craps out when it cannot reach a specific IP.

What I am trying to do now is to isolate the OPEN only. Right now it is giving me results in the format of:

     
     None
     '10.0.0.27'
     None
     '10.0.0.28'
     None
     open
     None
     '10.0.0.30'


Thank you for your help. I have been trying for several hours to figure this out :(

 I really appreciate it.

Comment: so the first print is returning None sometimes?

Comment: Yes.

I modified how it outputs the format a bit by doing the following:
'code'
import nmap
from netaddr import IPNetwork

nm = nmap.PortScanner()

for loop_1 in IPNetwork('10.0.0.1/26'):
    (nm.scan(loop_1.format(), '22')).get('state')
    try:
       state = (nm[loop_1.format()]['tcp'][22]['state'])
       if state == "open":
           print loop_1, " IS ", state
       elif state == "closed":
           pass
    except KeyError as e:
        print(e)
'code'

 
I really appreciate your help. This is my second month doing Python and there are so many things to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop code is broken:

```
for loop_1 in IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/26'):
    print nm.scan('loop_1', '22')
    print nm['loop_1']['tcp'][22]['state']
```

`loop_1` at the top is a variable which is the address to scan.  But then you later use a literal string `'loop_1'` which is not the variable.  You said if you use `loop_1` without quotes you get an error saying a string is needed instead of an IPAddress...so you must simply read the documentation for the IPAddress class to find how to convert it to a string (perhaps just `str(loop_1)`?) before putting it in the brackets.

Comment: that is not the problem

Comment: I tried to convert to a string and then it gives me a "KeyError: 10.0.0.0"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it's interesting how you say this is not the problem, yet your answer includes my proposed fixes.  I see you found additional things to fix, but claiming that use of a string where a variable was intended is "not the problem" seems a stretch.

Comment: the problem is namp will throw a keyerror for any ip that does not return any result so that is the real issue, the OP had also already had tried  `str(loop_1)` which works the same as loop_1.format().